# WSL上のUbuntuでgolangのビルドが失敗する

Tags: linux, go, ubuntu, windows-10, wsl

WSL(windows subsystem for linux)上のUbuntu18.04でgolang1.11をソースコードからビルドしようとしているのですが失敗します。
`/usr/local/`にインストールしたいので、

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ sudo git clone https://go.googlesource.com/go
$ cd go
$ sudo git checkout go1.11
$ cd src
$ sudo ./all.bash
```

を実行しました。

すでにこの環境にはgo1.10がインストールされており、
それをビルド用のgoとして使用しています。

エラーの内容を見ると、`/dev/full`がないのと、あともう一つmmapのことでエラーが出ているようなのですが解決するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか?

```
--- FAIL: TestDevices (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestDevices//dev/full_1:7 (0.00s)
        dev_linux_test.go:39: failed to stat device: no such file or directory
--- FAIL: TestRlimitAs (0.00s)
    syscall_linux_test.go:180: Mmap: unexpectedly suceeded after setting RLIMIT_AS
FAIL
FAIL    cmd/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix        0.427s
ok      cmd/vet 3.037s
ok      cmd/vet/internal/cfg    0.009s
2018/08/25 18:35:13 Failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: [ここ](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22020)などを眺めますと、一年ほど前から問題になっている様です。実際には `go tool dist test ...` でエラーが発生していて、最初のエラーに関して言えば WSL/Ubuntu には `/dev/full`(device file) がないので、、という事になります。もしかしたら、`mknod -m 666 /dev/full c 1 7` を root 権限で実行すれば `/dev/full` ファイルが作成されるかもしれませんが。。。後は[この記事](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu)に書かれている様に、pre-compile された go 1.10 をインストールする方法もあるかと思います。

Comment: `mknod -m 666 /dev/full c 1 7`を実行したら`/dev/full`についてのエラーは出なくなりました。
しかし、mmapのエラーはまだ発生しているようです。
何が原因なのでしょうか?

Comment: 問題が発生しているのは[ここ](https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/master/unix/syscall_linux_test.go#L178)ですが、WSL/Ubuntu では `success` となってしまう様です。`mmap(2)` システムコールへの対応がまだ不十分なのではないかと思います。